# Not able to type in HTML textBox --- Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html

Am having a html textbox in my razor view

```
<input type="text" id="txtComments" name="txtComments" placeholder="Enter your comments"
                                    style="width: 500px; height: 50px;" />
```

on hitting enter am making an ajax jquery call and saving the data. But am not able to type in textbox. if i change the `id="txtComments"` to somethig else am able to type.

What i am doing wrong ?

Added my script file :

```
$("#txtComments").keypress(function (e) {
    var comments = "";
    e.preventDefault();
    var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    if (code == 13) {
        comments = $("#txtComments").val();
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/SaveCommentsData",
            type: "POST",
            data: { 'CommentEntered': comments },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data, textStatus) {
                if (textStatus) {
                    $('#enteredComments').append('<span>' + comments + '</span>');
                    alert("Comment Saved");
                }
            },
            error: function (textstatus) {
                alert(textstatus);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you show your javascript as well?

Comment: Have you checked your JavaScript code to see if it's disabling txtComments? look for '#txtComments' in your code. You can try Find > Find in all solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are using `preventDefault()` which prevents the default action of the event which in this case is *typing*.

```
$("#txtComments").keypress(function (e) {
     var comments = "";
     // e.preventDefault();
```

You can move the statement to your if statement:

```
$("#txtComments").keypress(function (e) {
     var comments = "";
     if (e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        comments = this.value;
```

Comment: Correct. Why it is preventing ? not to take to a new URL am using it ! is it wrong ?

Comment: Just add the preventDefault to the top of the if block where you are checking for enter being pressed (keyCode == 13) - This way other keys arent affected and you can type.

Comment: @user2067567 By url do you mean `action` of the form element? If you want to only prevents the default action when Enter key is pressed you should move the statement to your `if` statement.

Comment: Thanks. gave it inside the loop fixed

Answer (score 1):

it's because you're using the prevent default for every keypress,

you only need to do it when you're pressing enter

```
if (code == 13) {
   e.preventDefault()
   //...
}
```

Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/johanhaest/q36Gg/